# Convert JSON to CSV in Azure Cosmos DB or Azure Blob

Tags: json, azure, csv, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I need to move JSON data in Azure Cosmos DB to Azure Blob and eventually need data to be in CSV format.

Found out there's a feature that converts CSV data to JSON but can't find the other way around..

It really doesn't matter where I convert data from JSON to CSV, either in Azure Cosmos DB or in Azure Blob. How could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using functions on either one?

Comment: @Kim Hi, any updates now? If you think my answer helps you ,please mark it.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on you requirements, I think [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) is your perfect option.

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal) to configure Cosmos DB Output and Azure Blob Storage Input.

***Input:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Then use Copy Pipelines to process data.

***Copy Pipelines:***

[image]

***Result:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Nice and elegant solution!