# Create collection on azure cosmos db too slow

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to automatically upload a CSV document to Azure Cosmos SQL API DB with Python using pydocumentdb. I'm using pandas to perform some data  preprocessing and then a transform every line in a JSON format. Finally, I create a document for every transformed line of the CSV.

The original csv is about 431 MB and 5173620 registers(lines), what it means that I need to ingest every register (line) as a new document. I found that the createDocument() function is very slow (more than one day to finish for all the registers). While a single-partition Cosmos db is limited to 10000 RUs, a Count all documents query spend 29025.92 RU and the result seems to be innacurrate.

I wonder if there is a way to enhance the performance of createDocument function. Also I would like to know how to define the RUs on the createCollection function. Any tip will be welcome.

```
# create document
coll_link = createColl(client, db_link, coll_id)

... preprocess a pandas Dataframe df...

# create a collection
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    doc = row.to_dict()
    client.CreateDocument(coll_link, doc)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You're creating a *collection* per document? I don't think that's what you meant to say. I'm assuming you're writing all documents to a single collection, correct?

Comment: Also: What is the Request Unit cost of each `CreateDocument()` call? (this is returned in the header) - with that, you would be able to figure out how many writes / second you could sustain. Also: Does your document contain a considerable number of properties? If so, consider creating a custom index policy, excluding all properties from indexing aside from the ones you need to search (this will reduce your RU cost, per write). It's entirely possible you're being throttled while trying to write (or maybe your bottleneck is in the serial for-loop and not Cosmos DB?)

Comment: Also: Cosmos DB collections are *not* limited to 10,000 RUs. Only single-partition collections are limited that way. If you create a partitioned collection (easiest to do this through the portal, at least as you're starting out), you can turn the RU up significantly higher (at least 100K RU without having to make a support request to go higher - I can't recall exactly)

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, I'm creating a writing all documents for a single collection. The outpout of createDocument() returns the body (my data) and some internal metadata as id, _ts, _etag,... How can I get the Request Unit that one document spend on his creation? Every document includes 10 properties, is that much for consider exclude properties? Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.I would like to know how to define the RUs on the createCollection function.

Add `offerThroughput` parameter.

```
databaseLink = "dbs/db"
coll = {
        "id": "testCreate",
        "indexingPolicy": {
            "indexingMode": "lazy",
            "automatic": False
        },
        "partitionKey": {
            "paths": [
              "/AccountNumber"
            ],
            "kind": "Hash"
        }
       }
collection_options = { 'offerThroughput': 2000}
client.CreateCollection(databaseLink , coll, collection_options)
```

> 2.I wonder if there is a way to enhance the performance of createDocument function.

Firstly, I don't think `createDocument()` function is very slow, instead it should be your whole import process is slow because of your data. Based on your description, you
don't confront error like [Request rate is too large](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8edaa6bf-a141-4363-b280-0964d0525129/request-rate-is-too-large-azure-document-db?forum=azurecosmosdb).Considering your economic issues , I don't recommend you endlessly increase RUs settings.You could consider use stored procedure to bulk import your data.Please refer to the sample in the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#example-bulk-importing-data-into-a-database-program).

> 3.Other choice.

You could use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db) to import data from csv file into cosmos db directly.Please refer to steps in my previous answer:[Convert JSON to CSV in Azure Cosmos DB or Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805997/convert-json-to-csv-in-azure-cosmos-db-or-azure-blob/50808443#50808443). Just convert input and output.

---

***Update:***

> Which are the benefits of using the bulk import procedure?

Cosmos db stored procedure is a snippet of js code which runs on the cosmos db server side. So if you use it to bulk import data , it could release the pressure of your client side.

> Can I add a Java coded store procedure on my Python code?

Cosmos DB Stored procedure is snippet of js code runs on the cosmos db server side. You could call the stored procedure in [cosmos db python sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-python).

> Concerning to Data Factory, it's possible to automatize the process to
>   generalize to different collections and dbs?

Based on the [Azure Data Factory Cosmos DB Dataset properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#dataset-properties), you need configure collection name. So you can't create dataset to different collections. Surely, you could change the collection name in sdk as your need instead of creating multiple datasets.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Very helpful information! I've some doubts. Which are the benefits of using the bulk import procedure? Can I add a Java coded store procedure on my Python code? Concerning to Data Factory, it's possible to automatize the process to generalize to different collections and dbs? (without creating a pipeline for every different collection) . The workflow will be: Python preprocess ==> Blob Storage(csv) ==> Data Factory ==> CosmosDB(json).  Thank you very much @Jay Gong

Comment: Can not see any change on your previus answer.

Comment: @Marc It's strange that my update gone. Forget it ! I updated the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! As far as I know stored procedure needs a partition key. In my case, that I have different collections with multiple fields and different sizes it needs a previous work to define good partitions keys. I will think about it. Thanks again.